Notation for convergence in distribution
I have the following expression as a result of limit in law, and I would like to better understand it in "modern terms": $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\Phi\Big(\frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\Big)\text{d}_y\mathbb{P}(W\le y|Z(0)),$$ where $\Phi$ denotes the cdf of a normal distribution.
In particular, I don't understand the notation $d_y\mathbb{P}(\cdot)$.
Moreover, I'd be interested (if I could fully understand it), to show that this expression corresponds to say, that the result of the limit is $W^{1/2}U$, where $W$ and $U\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ are independent. I think this is it, but couldn't fully justify it. Can anyone help please?
Source of the notation:  K.B. Athreya, P.E. Ney - Branching Processes, pp.211, 215.

The integral is taken in the sense of Lebesgue-Stieltjes. If such an integral ends with the $dv(x)$ symbol, it means that it is taken wrt a precise measure induced by the function $v(x)$. It is useful in probability theory beacause you can rigorously write the expectation of a random variable $X$ with cdf $F$ even when it is not specified whether its distribution is absolutely continuous, discrete or whatever. The following holds, no matter how its distribution behaves wrt the Lebesgue measure
$$\mathbb E\bigl(g(X)\bigr) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)\,dF(x).$$
In our case there are many letters, so the subscript $y$ is here to suggest that the expression following $d_y$ should be seen as a function of $y$.
I think that the lowercase letters $x, x_1, x_2, \sigma$ represent deterministic values, as usual. If this is the case, our integral is just the expectation of a function of $W$.
To see that, define the function $$g(y):=\Phi\Big(\frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\Big)\,\mathcal I\bigl\{x_1<y\le x_2\bigr\},$$
and introduce the cdf $F_{W\mid Z(0)}(y) := \mathbb{P}(W\le y|Z(0))$.
Then, what we have here is simply
\begin{align}
&\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\Phi\Big(\frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\Big)\text{d}_y\mathbb{P}(W\le y|Z(0))\\=&\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\Phi\Big(\frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\Big)\,\text{d}F_{W\mid Z(0)}(y)\\=&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi\Big(\frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\Big)\,\mathcal I\bigl\{x_1<y\le x_2\bigr\}\,\text{d}F_{W\mid Z(0)}(y)\\=&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(y)\,\text{d}F_{W\mid Z(0)}(y)\\=&\,\mathbb E\bigl(g(W)\mid Z(0)\bigr).
\end{align}
Let's get to the second part of the question. Let the random variables $U,W$ be iid $\mathrm N(0,\sigma^2)$ distributed. Then, if $0<x_1<x_2$, the truncated normal probability distribution function of $W$ given $x_1<W\le x_2$ is
$$f_{W\mid x_1<W\le x_2}(y)=\frac{\mathcal I\bigl\{x_1<y\le x_2\bigr\}}{\mathbb P(x_1<W\le x_2)}\frac1\sigma\varphi\biggl(\frac y\sigma\biggr).$$
Fix $x\in\mathbb R$ and compute the probability
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P(U\sqrt{W}\le x\mid x_1<W\le x_2)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathbb P(U\sqrt{y}\le x)f_{W\mid x_1<W\le x_2}(y)\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(x_1<W\le x_2)}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathbb P(U\sqrt{y}\le x)\frac1\sigma\varphi\biggl(\frac y\sigma\biggr)\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(x_1<W\le x_2)}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathbb P\biggl(\frac{U}{\sigma}\le \frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\biggr)f_{\!_W}(y)\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(x_1<W\le x_2)}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathbb \Phi\Bigl( \frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\Bigr)f_{\!_W}(y)\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(x_1<W\le x_2)}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathbb \Phi\Bigl( \frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\Bigr)\,dF_{\!_W}(y)\\
&=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(x_1<W\le x_2)}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathbb \Phi\Bigl( \frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}\Bigr)\,d_y\mathbb P(W\le y),
\end{align}
which is somewhat similar to our integral.

Thank you a lot for your answer! Do you have some thoughts on my second part of the question (to say that the expression corresponds to $W^{1/2}U$)? From your answer I still don't get how to say that these forms correspond.

You already have an excellent answer to the first part of your question. For the second part, let $U$ and $W$ be independent given $Z(0)$, and let ${U \mid Z(0)} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Consider the probability
$$
p = P(x_1 < W \le x_2, W^{1/2} U \le x \mid Z(0)).
$$
By conditioning inside on $W$, we have
\begin{align}
  p &= E[1_{(x_1, x_2]}(W) 1_{(-\infty, x]}(W^{1/2} U) \mid Z(0)]\\
  &= E[E[
    1_{(x_1, x_2]}(W) 1_{(-\infty, x]}(W^{1/2} U)
  \mid
    W, Z(0)
  ] \mid Z(0)]\\
  &= E[1_{(x_1, x_2]}(W) E[
    1_{(-\infty, x]}(W^{1/2} U)
  \mid
    W, Z(0)
  ] \mid Z(0)]\\
  &= E[1_{(x_1, x_2]}(W) P(W^{1/2} U \le x \mid W, Z(0)) \mid Z(0)]\\
  &= E\left[
    1_{(x_1, x_2]}(W) \Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sigma W^{1/2}}\right)
  \;\bigg|\;
    Z(0)
  \right]\\
&= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} {
  \Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sigma y^{1/2}}\right) \, dF_{W \mid Z(0)}(y).
}
\end{align}

Thank you a lot for the clarification. Now, since both answers complete each other, I wouldn't know whom to attribute the accepted answer + bounty.
